# How to embed only Alfresco Repository in individual project

Tags: alfresco, ecm

Already have implemented Alfresco CMIS to create, delete and modify files connecting to the Alfresco Community (server), but we need to include/embed the Alfresco Repository to our project, we **DON'T** need the *share* interface or REST API, only the **repository**.

Is is possible or there is other alternatives?

Comment: Do you need explicitly the Alfresco repository or do you just need a content repository?

Comment: @Thomas I prefer Alfresco because I already implemented Alfresco CMIS, but what'd you suggest?

Comment: Alfresco is definitely very powerful, but challenging to embed and to strip down to your actual requirements. For an embedded repo I would rather go for Apache Jackrabbit Oak. It can be easily embedded as a Jar dependency (also scaled out later on) and can be accessed through the javax.jcr API.
See https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/use_getting_started.html for details on how to include it.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Share, just don't deploy the Share war file. It's not necessary to run the core webapp.

Not including the rest API would be more difficult. I believe it would be possible to just include the core services, but it may be more trouble than it's worth. Why would you want to exclude the Rest API?

If you are dead set on stripping down the product, I would recommend disabling context files and commenting servlets out of the web.xml until you get a more "lightweight" version of the product.

Comment: I didn't explain clear enough, we have the Alfresco Community deployed at our server, I know there is many modules (war), but I want to embed the Alfresco.war (manager/repository) inside my project.

Comment: You would need to use the alfresco.war as the base and build your project around it. Think about it this way: you're application probably has a lot less code than Alfresco, even a stripped down Alfresco. It's going to be easier to add your code to Alfresco rather than vice-versa.